# How to avoid button merging in navigation bar in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, navigation

I have a navigation bar in my jgrid and I've added so many buttons that they are superimposing to each other. This way it's difficult to see which button is which.

[image: my navigation bar]

I'd like to know how I can avoid this. Could I have two navigation bars? or a two-row bar? Maybe deleting the pager?

Thanks in advance

Natalia

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I solved it with jQuery adding more rows.

```
        var pagerNav =  $("#pagernav")
        var gridnavTbody = $(pagerNav).find("tbody").first();
        var navgridrows = $(pagerNav).find("td").first().siblings("td").addBack();
        $(navgridrows).appendTo($(gridnavTbody));
        $(navgridrows).wrap( "<tr><tr/>");
        $(navgridrows).children().css("text-align","center");
        $(navgridrows).attr("align","center");
        $(navgridrows).children().css("float","none");
        $(pagerNav).css("height","75px");
```

And this was the result:

[image]

Html before jQuery code
[image: Html before jQuery code]

and this is after jQuery
[image: Html after jQuery code]

Comment: Thanks hect0r90. I'm a newbie with jqgrid and I don't know exactly how to use your code. 
Does the navigation bar have a "tbody" "td" "tr"? or should I write it? Why the "_" after "gbox"? thanks

Comment: I updated the code. The first line was only because I have multiple grids with differents names, but you can define here directly the pagerNav. The "tbody", "td" and "tr" was already there, I only surrounded each "td" with another "tr".